# Transferring HTML snippet in an XML file

Tags: html, xml, plist, data-transfer

I want to transfer an HTML snippet in a plist file. For example I'd like to include:

```
<a href="http://www.something.com?a=1&b=2">My Link</a>
```

in my plist file that my iOS app downloads from a remote server. **How can I include an HTML snippet inside an XML formatted file like a plist that's downloaded from a remote server**?